# How can Swift insert just 1 backslash \ in String?

Tags: swift3, backslash

Is it possible to replace white space " " with "\ " ?
For example, I need to do make change as follows: 
"computer science" to "computer\ science".

This is to make my other command line executable with some directory that contains white space.  It fails with white space, but doing:

```
myText = "computer science"
myTextRevised = myText.replacingOccurance(of: " ", with "\\ ")
```

but this just makes `myText = "computer\\ science"`, which I don’t understand why two backslash appears.

It cannot leave just one backslash like, 
"computer\ science".

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: The backslash is displayed escaped using the escape character of a backslash. It is the IDE way of displaying back slashes in strings. Try printing the string instead of inspecting it in the Xcode / Playground.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks for responding.  First, I did it in my actual code, and noticed my value just simply had two backslashes when I printed for debugging.  So, I started doing experiment in playground.  In both, they gave me same result.  I am stuck with this... It does not make sense that first escaping backslash is actually being a value in the code... I wonder if this is a bug.

Comment: no, this is not a bug, your code is correct. The only possible thing is that you are misinterpreting the displayed strings. the code itself works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
myText = "computer science"
myTextRevised = myText.replacingOccurance(of: " ", with "\\ ")
```

Would actually store *computer\science* in `myTextRevised`. 
As expected first backslash is used to escape the second (that is to be displayed).

Oh! I guess you are seeing it in Playground. Playground would show you it like that. Didn't you observe that playground also shows \n to you for each print statement?

Answer (score 0):

**Simply you can Add  "\"  backslash in ios swift language in such a way :**

```
var str = "My string" + "\\"
print("\(string")
```